# Portable LaTeX system for Mac

Tags: installing, texlive, mac

So my MacBook Air broke down, and I plan to make use of the Macs in the university library to write papers. But the problem is: I do not have admin control there (so I cannot install anything) and LaTeX is not installed originally.

So I wonder if there is a way to put latex system & TexShop into a USB and use them on those Macs?

---

Final edit:

Thanks all for the advice. Succeeded installing a working TexLive system on my portable hard drive. But my story has a funny ending: It turns out that the university iMac does not run any software besides those already installed, nor can I use the Terminal or any advanced features. Well, I dig out my old notebook with Windows 7 and THE END : )

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe of interest: there are online options like sharelatex and writelatex (though I have never used them).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried one such product (not the ones you mentioned, though), but it was really slow. But maybe these two are better, I'll try.

Comment: It turns out the writelatex is the one I used...And I tried sharelatex, which is quite nice! Fast and easy to use. The only things to complain is no click&sync feature and no controal over the code font. But it's really a good solution!

Comment: Related [Does standalone LaTeX exist?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44137/15717) and [Multi-OS Portable TeX system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33095/15717)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downloading [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) . Create a folder called `texlive2013` inside your home directory and install `TeX Live` there. You could also install it on a portable
hard drive or a large capacity memory stick, but in the latter case compiling may be painfully slow.

This worked on a linux machine on which I do not have admin privileges (it was necessary because it had a prehistoric TeX installation). I think it will work on a Mac as well. You will probably need to manually edit your login script so that the path environment variable makes `latex`, `pdflatex` etc. available from the terminal.

For an editor, try running `emacs` from the terminal; it may be installed already. If it doesn't work, you could try `emacs -nw` (which runs `emacs` in the terminal window itself). Failing that, there is always `vi`, or just edit your `LaTeX` files using `TextEdit`, or  another text editor that is already installed.

**EDIT**

On second thoughts, you can probably install an editor of your choice in your home directory or on a portable storage device. Most OS X applications don't care where they are installed.

Comment: Then from the unzipped root, just execute `./install-tl` and a GUI will be displayed. Mercifully it allows you to change the target dir so that you don't crowd your `/usr/bin` with loads of junk. I even set the info and man files to be written to `/tmp`!