# How to make a USB LaTeX Stick for OS X?

Tags: installing, mactex

> I want to make a USB Stick with a stand-alone LaTeX for OS X devices.

Is there any possibility to doing that?

**If yes, how can i do it?** All versions for LaTeX on Mac i found needed a system library to install.

Comment: Hello and [welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I'm afraid your question is a duplicate. There are similar Q/A [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/multi-os-portable-tex-system) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95644/portable-latex-on-thumbdrive).